# Stop binding child div, to bind it with another model

Tags: javascript, razor, knockout.js

This is my view:

```
@model Horeko.Web.ViewModels.MyUpdateViewModel
<div id="main">
    <div>
          more nested divs with data bindings
          <div id="importDiv" data-bind="stopBinding: true">@Html.Partial("MyPartialView", Model.ImportSettings)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code in js looks like this:

```
var myInfoModel = function (model) {
        var self = this;

        var mapping = {
            'include': ["desc", "name", "start", "end", "importSettings"],
            'copy': ["id"]
        };
        ko.mapping.fromJS(model, mapping, self);
}

var infoModel = new myInfoModel(model);//model is from the view

var infoPanel = $("main")[0];
ko.applyBindings(infoModel, infoPanel);
ko.cleanNode(infoModel.importSettings, $("#importDiv")[0]);
ko.applyBindings(infoModel.importSettings, $("#importDiv")[0]);
```

I would like to exclude importDiv from binding here and bind it with another infoModel.importSettings. So do the same as I do for the 'main' div above, but for the 'import' div. However I am unable to do that because I get the error 'You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the cleanNode approach is that the bindings still get attached once initially so they and any other bindings within that node have to parse without errors.

To get around this you could get rid of the second "applyBindings" and use an "if" binding with an observable boolean to tell your bindings when to render the inner div instead.

```js
var myInfoModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.ready = ko.observable(false);
    setTimeout(function(){
      self.info = 'Inner Bindings';
      self.ready(true);
    }, 1000);    
}

var infoModel = new myInfoModel();//model is from the view
var infoPanel = $("#main")[0];
ko.applyBindings(infoModel, infoPanel);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
    <div>
        <span>Outer Binding</span>
        
        <div data-bind="if: ready">
            <div id="importDiv">
                <span data-bind="text: info"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If that doesn't work for your scenario you could alternately remove the inner div from the DOM before calling applyBindings, and then re-attach it once you're ready to bind it.

```js
var myInfoModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.importSettings = { info: 'Inner Bindings' };
}

var infoModel = new myInfoModel();//model is from the view
var infoPanel = $("#main")[0];
var $importPanel = $("#importDiv").detach();
ko.applyBindings(infoModel, infoPanel);

setTimeout(function(){
    $importPanel.appendTo("#main");
    ko.applyBindings(infoModel.importSettings, $("#importDiv")[0]);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
    <div>
        <span>Outer Binding</span>
        
        <div id="importDiv">
            <span data-bind="text: info"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```